# How can I have a class pass its own type in the generics of a parameter name?

Tags: c#

I have got two `abstract` classes: `Particle` and `ParticleHub<T> where T : Particle`.

I want, when I inherit `Particle`, for its constructor to require a `ParticleHub` of its respective type to be passed as a parameter. I want its constructor to be like this:

```cs
ParticleHub</*type of the inheriting class*/> _particleHub;

public Particle(ParticleHub</*type of the inheriting class*/> particleHub, OtherParameters otherParameters)
{
    _particleHub = particleHub;
    //use other parameters
}
```

If I write `ParticleHub<typeof(this)>` I get overloaded with errors that make me think I broke the syntax for the rest of the file. If I do `ParticleHub<this.GetType()>` I get the same problem, but only with fewer errors. Though with that one, I can understand that I can't use a function in a parameter type like that.

So how do I go about this?

Comment: Hm, if you are writing "this class" you know what it is... So write the type yourself

Comment: Thats what I am saying. @MichałTurczyn

Comment: @MichałTurczyn the problem is that this is an `abstract class`, so I cannot predict what class type is going to inherit it. But if a class _is_ going to inherit it, I want it to only allow `ParticleHub</*the child class type*/>` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have no other choise i think but to pass the type as other generic. See the exaple how it is done in terms of fluent builders as I think it is very close what You want to have: [Link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/code-maze.com/fluent-builder-recursive-generics/amp/).

Like:

```
FePatricle<T, U> where T: Particle, U: FeParticle<T, U>
```

Looks crazy but it should do the trick in the constructor:

```
public FeParticle(ParticleHub<U>...
```

EDIT:

Or more likely as far as I understand:

```
FePatricle<T>: Particle where T: FeParticle<T>
```

So `FePartivle` extends `Particle` and it carries with itself its own type `T`?

Comment: So in this case, is `FeParticle` equivalent to `ParticleHub` or to `Particle`?

Comment: Particle: `FePatricle<T>: Particle`. Couldnt't come up with some other exple that iron particles

Answer (score 0):

Simple example below of an interface and generic pattern

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");


        IChair chair = new Chesterfield<Arm>(new Arm());
        chair.Sit();
        Console.Write(chair.HasSat());
    }
}

public interface IChair
{
    void Sit();
    bool HasSat();
}

public interface IPart
{

}

public class Chesterfield<TPart> : Chair<TPart> where TPart : IPart
{
    public Chesterfield(TPart part) => _part = part;
    private bool _hasSat;
    private readonly TPart _part;

    public override void Sit()
    {
        _hasSat = true;
    }

    public override bool HasSat() => _hasSat;
}

public abstract class Chair<TPart> : IChair where TPart : IPart
{
    public abstract void Sit();
    public abstract bool HasSat();
}

public class Arm : IPart
{

}

public class Back : IPart
{

}

public class Leg
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the inherited class itself, as below.

```
        public abstract class Particle
        {
        }

        public abstract class ParticleHub<T> where T : Particle
        { 
        }

        public class k1 : Particle
        {
            ParticleHub<k1> _particleHub = null;
            public k1(ParticleHub<k1> ph)
            {
                _particleHub = ph;
            }
        }
```